# how can I make the expo Icon adapt?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have configured the expo icon just like below in app.json file, however, the icon is not adapting. Looks like it is using cache, because I've changed the icon sometimes but still the same thing. Any idea how to fix this?

```
"expo": {
"name": "Mirar APP",
"slug": "mirar-app",
"version": "1.0.14",
"orientation": "portrait",
"icon": "./assets/mirar1024.png",
"userInterfaceStyle": "light",
"splash": {
  "image": "./assets/mirarLogo.png",
  "resizeMode": "contain",
  "backgroundColor": "#000000"
},
"updates": {
  "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
},
"assetBundlePatterns": [
  "**/*"
],
"ios": {
  "supportsTablet": true
},
"android": {
  "package": "com.MirarApp",
  "versionCode": 15,
  "adaptiveIcon": {
    "foregroundImage": "./assets/mirar1024.png",
    "backgroundColor": "#000000"
  }
}, ...
```

I have tried some reset command that I found and also tried checking expo docs.